# How does this compile without errors?

Tags: kotlin, generics

```kotlin
fun main() {
    print(test(1, "abc", 4))
}

fun <T> test(criteria: T, actual: T, points: Int): Int {
    if (criteria == null) return 0
    return if (criteria == actual) points else 0
}

// prints 0
```

The arguments provided in main function does not match generics contract in the test function since the first argument and the second argument should be of the same type. How does this compile? Tested with Kotlin 1.7.10, here's the kotlin playground link: https://pl.kotl.in/s9fJVUw0D

Comment: What's `list` used for?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't meet the contract. Why are you expecting it to fail?

Comment: I think the OP is expecting the `==` between `Int` and `String` to fail, but that's not what's happening there.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini sorry the list is confusing, edited it out now :)

Comment: @Tenfour04 it doesn't meet the contract because the first argument and the second argument should be of the same type. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini == between Int and String should definitely fail. But the code shouldn't compile because type arguments do not match.

Comment: To better grasp the idea, I invite you to look at the generated bytecode of your test function. ;)

Comment: `== between Int and String should definitely fail.` In your method they are assumed as `Any` not Int and String.

Comment: @SarpBaşaraner technically, both arguments are of type `Comparable` or even `Any`, so they meet the contract. Your contract is not exactly that the 2 arguments must have matching types. The contract is actually that both arguments must be subtypes of the same `T`. Since there is no constraint on `T`, all pairs of arguments satisfy the condition if you set `T=Any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the Bytecode of your test function, you will immediately notice the limitation(?) of the JVM when it comes to "generics".

```
  // declaration: int test<T>(T, T, int)
  public final static test(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;I)I
```

In other words, Java has this thing called [type erasure](https://dev.java/learn/type-erasure/) which is a pain when you come from other generic-supporting languages.

What you *maybe* want, if you want the code to fail is to play with the Covariance/Invariance rules...

so perhaps:

```
fun <T: Int?> test2(criteria: T, actual: T, points: Int): Int {
    if (criteria == null) return 1
    return if (criteria == actual) points else 0
}
```

Will work for integers.

```
print(test2(1, 2, 4))
```

will print 0

```
print(test2(1, 1, 4))
```

Will print 4

```
print(test2(1, "2", 4))
```

Will fail.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. So is there no way to enforce two arguments of same type in Java generics?

Comment: There kinda is, refresh the answer ;) Also look at [the Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) for variance for better/more info.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that the problem comes from type erasure. Type erasure is a runtime issue, not a compile time issue. At compile time, all types are very well defined. The problem here is that OP is forgetting that functions accept subtypes of their argument types. If you set `T` to `Any` or `Comparable`, passing a string and an integer is perfectly valid, regardless of type erasure.

Comment: @Joffrey my exact use case is to do a validation of multiple fields of types string, int, and boolean. If I was able to reduce it to int subtypes I probably wouldn't even use generics. I assume it's currently not possible to enforce it with current JVM generics? I want args of type T to be exactly the same subtype of Comparable.

Comment: I partially agree with Joffrey that your test function is relying on `Comparable` for that's all you really do, but I still think it's related to how Java orchestrates Generics and ultimately it's the runtime that affects you. The code will happily compile regardless in your case because you're not constraining "the type/subtype" and so `Object` fits the bill.

Comment: It could be argued this has nothing to do with type erasure. OP was expecting it to fail at compile time because they didn't realize T could simply be Comparable or Any and satisfy the compile-time constraint.